# Detect that statusBar had collapsed

Tags: android, statusbar

I implemented in my app button that expand statusBar although the statusBar is hidden. for achive this I do this inside OnClick:

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Utils.showTitleBar(ctx, false);
    Utils.setNotification(ctx);
}
```

This work well, however, i want to hide statusBar when the statusBar collaps, and to achive this, i implements this:

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        Log.i("TAG", "  boolen:" + Boolean.toString(hasFocus));
        if (hasFocus && pref.getBoolean("belStatus", false))
            Utils.showTitleBar(ctx, true);
    }
```

This work fine too but just one time. in the next time that I press on the Button and expand the statusBar, when I collapse it, the 'onWindowDocousChanged' never called anymore so the statusBar remain.
So, there is another way to detect that statusBar collapsed? Or someone could help me figure why the 'onWindowFocousChanged' not called in second time?

If it help the method I using is those:

```
 public static void setNotification(Context ctx){
        Object sbservice = ctx.getSystemService( "statusbar" );
        Class<?> statusbarManager;
        try {
            statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method showsb;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
            }
            else {
                showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
            }
            showsb.invoke( sbservice );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 public static void showBelTitleBar(MainActivity ctx, boolean show){
        View status = ctx.findViewById(R.id.status_bar);
        if (show) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                ctx.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            } else {
                ctx.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }

        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                ctx.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            } else {
                ctx.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it will help someone, I achieved my goal by adding some delay to the opening of the notification bar. this way the onWindowFocusChanged() method always called as needed.
So now my code implemented this way:

```
findViewById(R.id.status_bar).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
                Utils.showBelTitleBar(ctx, false, updateClkBtry, handler);
                ctx.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Utils.setNotification(ctx);
                    }
                }, 100);
                return false;
            }
        });
```